# Using the Find VBA function with Defined String

Tags: vba, excel, find

Hey maybe I'm not seeing something obvious here but how can you use the Find VBA function with a predefined variable. I'm using a concatenation of a string assigned from a user form and just "total " in front of it, yet I can't return the row.

Below is my code

```
Dim HBWS As Worksheet
Dim TickerString As String
TickerString = "Total " & TTB
Set HBWS = Sheets("Hoenheimm Worksheet")


BorrowColumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Borrow").Column 'Works just fine
TickerRow = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:=TickerString).Row 'Throws an error
```

Note that TTB is set to a ticker ex. AAPL, and I can check in my local windows that Tickerstring is in fact = to "Total AAPL"

I would expect the .Row column to give me the row on my worksheet as to where this string is located.

EDIT: the error being thrown is as follows...

> "Run-Time error '91':
>
> Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Any throughts,
Thanks

Comment: Then `TickerString` is not found on the sheet.

Comment: Don't even make it that far. I just edited my post to detail the error.

Comment: If `.Find` fails it returns `Nothing` so accessing `.Row` will throw error 91. Test by seeing if `range("A1").Value = TickerString` is true (replace A1 with the address of the cell with the real corresponding value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're invoking `Range.Find`. That method returns a `Range` object reference - and when it does not find what it's told to look for, it returns `Nothing`, i.e. a *null reference*.

```
TickerRow = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:=TickerString).Row 'Throws an error
```

What this code is doing (and the working instruction just above it), is *assuming* that `Find` returns a valid object reference.

Apparently `HBWS.Cells` does not contain `"Total " & TTB` (whatever `TTB` is), so your code is effectively trying to invoke `Range.Row` against a `Range` reference that's `Nothing`... which is illegal, and raises run-time error 91 as you're experiencing.

You shouldn't assume that `Find` will return a valid reference, ever. Split it up, and validate the returned object reference with an `If ... Is Nothing` check:

```
Set tickerResult = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:=TickerString)
If Not tickerResult Is Nothing Then
    tickerRow = tickerResult.Row
Else
    'tickerString was not found. 
    'watch for leading/trailing/extra spaces if the string does *look* legit.
End If
```

---

When calling `Range.Find`, you should always provide a value for the optional parameters, because its implementation "remembers" values from previous invocations, and this is easily bug-prone.

Comment: So, I meant to ask, why the name change?

Comment: Super helpful and very detailed answer.

I'll also be implementing the check you added, didn't realize that was best practice but makes obvious sense.