# How do I change my macro into a Worksheet_Change event Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that I call when the workbook closes. It checks the columns in two tables on separate worksheets and assigns row numbers based on what it finds.

**`Worksheet_Change` handler is located on the sheet with `Projects` range. `Database` range is located on another worksheet in the same workbook.**

Whenever I call the macro anywhere else, it either generates an error or causes an usual bug where excel is partially frozen (anyone know what the hell this is?!?!?!).

Anyway, my last resort before giving up is to change the macro into a worksheet change event and I was wondering if I could get some help creating this.
The original macro:

```
Sub FindRow()
'This module verifies row numbers in the database by matching them to the opportunities in the Projects
'worksheet. It then assigns row numbers in the Projects worksheet.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Set foundRng = Sheets("Database").Range("C:C").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My proposed change:

```
 Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim Records As Range

        Set Records = Range("Records")
        If Not Application.Intersect(Records, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim LastRow As Long    
        LastRow = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim foundRng As Range
        For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
            Set foundRng = Sheets("Database").Range("C:C").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
            End If
        Next rng
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
    End Sub
```

However, I keep getting an error on the line that defines the variable `LastRow`.
I get an application-defined error even though everything is defined properly before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What is the value of lastrow?

Comment: @SJR debugging pulls up nothing because it doesn't like the line of code so doesn't even bother running it. When it is running as a macro in a stand-alone module, it does give me the correct line, which is the last row of the table.

Comment: What happens if you change `Application.ThisWorkbook` to just `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and try stepping through.

Comment: @MattCremeens same error

Comment: You're not saying what the error is... does [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49456230/1188513) fix your problem by any chance?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I already did. Application-defined error. Also, it does not allow me to step-over when I put a breakpoint on that line of code.

Comment: The odd part is, after it causes an error, I cannot select any cell on any of the worksheets in the workbook, even after I end the macro. I have to close the workbook and re-open it to work on it again. It's like it's trying to crash and then forgets about it or something.

Comment: The obvious problem is that there is nothing on that sheet.

Comment: I believe @MathieuGuindon is looking for the full error message.

Comment: @MattCremeens First error I get is Automation error. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. Once I End the macro and try again. I get an Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: @SJR That is not the case at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, since it's impossible to answer without an [edit] that clarifies what sheets are involved. See if you can come up with a proper [mcve] that reproduces the problem and skips the fluff.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Why would you vote to close this? You know, the owners put out a message about how this place isn't friendly to new programmers and you're embodying that right now. I included both the original code and my modification. My original works and I was simply asking why my change isn't working. I can't provide an example because there isn't a problem until there is a problem. I was hoping one of you guys could see something I couldn't. Instead you choose to dismiss the entire thread.

Comment: @Remi you've been asked to clarify which sheets are involved and to provide a minimal example. Do you know why that has been asked? To work out why your code does not work. So, if you don't want to provide that, don't be surprised if the question gets closed.

Comment: The worksheet_change event only works for the activesheet. , if you get an error during the worksheet change event, you may have to reset "EnableEvents" to true.

Comment: @teylyn No, Mathieu said to close the thread before bringing up the need for an MCV. From my perspective, the question was pretty clear. That is my irritation. If he had asked for an MCV, maybe I would have responded differently, but for now, close the thread. I'll get my help elsewhere.

Comment: RE "*The odd part is, after it causes an error, I cannot select any cell on any of the worksheets in the workbook, even after I end the macro. I have to close the workbook and re-open it to work on it again. It's like it's trying to crash and then forgets about it or something.*" - that's because you have `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to `False`. Type `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and everything will be back to normal. Excel isn't repainting itself because you're specifically telling it not to do that.

Comment: ^^ (cont) and this is why you need to handle runtime errors whenever you involve `Application.ScreenUpdating` state - so you can capture the error and recover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Worksheet_Change` handles is located on the sheet with `Projects` range. Database range is located on another worksheet in the same workbook. – Remi 1 min ago

This means `rng` is also on the `Projects` sheet:

```
For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
```

(BTW `Me.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)` would have been much less ambiguous here)

You're handling a `Worksheet_Change` event on the `Projects` sheet, which Excel fires whenever a cell value changes on the `Projects` sheet. Then *inside that handler*, you do this:

```
rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
```

With `rng` being a range on the `Projects` sheet, you're entering a recursive cycle of sheet changes, and *that* is likely what's crashing your code.

When you make worksheet changes *while handling worksheet changes*, you need to tell Excel "it's okay, I got this", by preventing it from re-firing the `Worksheet.Change` event every time:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

'...code...

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Moreover, when you toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, you're telling Excel "don't repaint yourself until I say so" - that can speed things up considerably, in a lot of cases, however it also means you need to toggle it back on manually if something bad happens.

You can avoid this by implementing an error handler - here's the principle:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '...code...

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume 'F8 takes you to the error-throwing statement
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! I added the `On Error GoTo` and `CleanExit` and `CleanFail`  lines of code you suggested and it works! And without error. I do not know why it works but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated what sheet is the activesheet that has the worksheet_change event.

Any way, here is a code to find the last row in column B sheet "Projects"

```
    Dim LastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Projects")

    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LastRow & " is the last row in Column B Sheet Projects!"
```

Comment: The sheet containing the `Records` range is the active sheet. But that is not the problem. The problem is the line `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` being okay in one version of the code, and then not working in another version.

Comment: @Remi `Set Records = [Me.]Range("Records")` already made that clear. What we *still* don't know is whether `Sheets("Projects")` is the same sheet or not.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It checks the columns in two tables on separate worksheets and assigns row numbers based on what it finds. I said that in the OP. Projects is in another worksheet.

Comment: @Remi okay look, one last time: specifically which worksheet is this `Worksheet_Change` handler written in? Contrary to what you seem to imply, "another sheet" is NOT clear.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon `Worksheet_Change` handles is located on the sheet with `Projects` range. `Database` range is located on another worksheet in the same workbook.

Comment: @Remi then [this is exactly what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358442/how-do-i-change-my-macro-into-a-worksheet-change-event-excel-vba/50358982?noredirect=1#comment87734048_50358442)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171113/discussion-between-remi-and-mathieu-guindon).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am missing something. The code runs when it is called as a module on `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. I feel I need to make that clear. I am trying to change it into a `Worksheet_Change` event handler so it can work while the user is still using the workbook. Should I change my 'Target` to something other than `range`? I am truly not understanding your suggestions.